# Set a text label to have at least N lines in objective -c

Tags: ios, objective-c, label

I have a text label with a fixed width. Now I want to make this label to have at least N lines, that is, if the text is short than N lines, the rest lines should be blank lines. Otherwise, if the text is longer than N lines (say it has X lines), I want the label to be exactly X lines long.

So is there some way to set (_lable.numberOfLines >= N) ?

Any help would be appreciated.

===========

Thanks for all the answers. Finally I used masonry's mas_greaterThanOrEqualTo to solve this.

Comment: Create a height constraint on the label and set the constant to `>= label.font.lineHeight * N`, then set the `numberOfLines` to 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use `constraints` for handle this :
1 ) open your story board
2)  create new ’height’ constraint' for your label 
3 ) set the `constant`  of constraint
to  :
@dan :
label.font.lineHeight * n  (minimum of height for 1 lines)

4 ) set the numberOfLines for you Label to '0'